# MySQL Syntax Errors code on page

Tags: php, mysql

just wondered if someone spot my error i really cant see it but i have sql code on my page starting at get_sql thanks

```
<?
    if (!empty($item_details[$counter]['name'])) {

        $main_image = $db -> get_sql_field("SELECT media_url FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "auction_media WHERE
            auction_id='" . $item_details[$counter],['auction_id'] . "' AND media_type=1 AND upload_in_progress=0 ORDER BY media_id ASC LIMIT 0,1", 'media_url');

        $auction_link = process_link('auction_details', array('name' => $item_details[$counter]['name'], 'auction_id' => $item_details[$counter]['auction_id']));?>
```

Comment: just post your error and we can spot it

Answer (score 0):

your error is here you have extra comma here

```
 WHERE auction_id='" . $item_details[$counter],['auction_id'] . "'
```

change to

```
 WHERE auction_id='" . $item_details[$counter]['auction_id'] . "'
```

TRY this

```
    $main_image = $db->get_sql_field("SELECT media_url FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "auction_media WHERE
        auction_id='" . $item_details[$counter]['auction_id'] . "' AND media_type=1 AND upload_in_progress=0 ORDER BY media_id ASC LIMIT 0,1");
```

Comment: hi sorry i think this is maybe my problem the template is not getting my var so the error would be on $main_image

Comment: function set($name, $value)
 {
  $this->vars[$name] = $value;

 }

Comment: since you dont provide your error , difficult at se

Comment: Undefined variable: about 12 but i've just realised all my errors are connected my template is not receiving the variables this function is the problem function set($name, $value) { $this->vars[$name] = $value; }

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
auction_id='" . $item_details[$counter],['auction_id'] . "'
```

to

```
auction_id="' . $item_details[$counter]['auction_id'] . '"
```

here you need **"** to cover your string not **'** & also the comma maybe as **echo_Me** said

Comment: i guess i have answered it , why answer again same answer ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in:

```
$item_details[$counter],['auction_id']
```

Just remove the comma.

Comment: i guess i have answered it , why answer again same answer ?

Comment: You submitted your answer after I loaded my page, I never saw it.

Answer (score 0):

Undefined variable: about 12 but i've just realised all my errors are connected my template is not receiving the variables this function is the problem `function set($name, $value) { $this->vars[$name] = $value; }

when i print the request i get this
session Object
(
    [vars] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

)

```
    ## assign variables that will be used in the template used.
function set($name, $value)
{
    $this->vars[$name] = $value;

}

## process the template file
function process($file)
{
    @extract($this->vars);
    ob_start();
    include($this->path . $file);
    $contents = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    return $contents;

}
```